# Vim color syntax highlighting changes not having any effect

Tags: themes, vim

I use vim on webfaction through putty and would like to change the colours used in the syntax highlighting. I have installed some example themes and then tried to change the colors in those themes to match the ones I want. For some reason this strategy does not work. What am I doing wrong? Is it because I'm using putty, or is it something weird with webfaction's linux or vim? Or is my logic just wrong?

I created `/home/user/.vim/color/theme.vim`
I then load the them by adding colorscheme theme to my `/home/user/.vimrc`

Aside from my color changes not working on obvious parts like

```
hi Normal      guifg=#ffffff guibg=#000000 gui=none
```

it also does not seem to implement all the theme changes when I just use the theme without changing it. Is there something better than putty I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terminal mode, the `ctermbg` and `ctermfg` keys are used instead of `guibg` and `guifg`. It uses Xterm colors. See for example [this table](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Xterm256_color_names_for_console_Vim) for a rough mapping, and even a VIM script that shows a color table.

So you would need to change your line to:

```
hi Normal ctermfg=15 ctermbg=0 guifg=#ffffff guibg=#000000 gui=none
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly this also does not seem to work (assuming Normal is normal text). Tried ctermfg=15 and ctermfg=14, but they do not give white or cyan.

Comment: What happens if you use `White` or `Cyan` instead of numbers?

Comment: Do they give you colors, but not the correct ones? Then you need to check the Putty configuration and whether the `$TERM` variable is correctly set (it should be something like `xterm-256color`).

Comment: @DarkDust: Don't see anything about $TERM in the settings, but under window, colours 'Allow terminal to use xterm 256-colour mode' is ticked yes.

Comment: @romainl: hi Normal ctermfg=Cyan ctermbg=0 guifg=#ffffff guibg=#000000 gui=none works!!! Unfortunately I still don't know how to use the colours from DarkDust's link, now that I have this knowledge

Comment: Googling based on that information seems to deliver some results, so I'll take this as answered.

Comment: `:help cterm-colors` will give you the valid color names you need.

Comment: Thanks, you rule. Any idea why names work, but numbers don't?

Comment: Also, why can I only use 16 colours and not 256?

Comment: That's most likely an issue with Putty and/or the $TERM variable. See the [VIM page about 256 colors](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim). Let the linked [Perl test script](http://www.frexx.de/xterm-256-notes/data/256colors2.pl) run to see whether the terminal can handle 256 colors.

Comment: Thanks. Adding set t_Co=256 seems to have fixed all my problems. Getting more colours and numbers now also work. Thanks again.